# count latest occurrence of a status - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a *sort* of inelegant solution for the following problem and I was wondering if there was a better way to handle the following sort of dataset,

I have a small data set of around 150k rows which has 3 essential rows I'm trying to wrangle :

```
ID  Status Week
1   base   1
1   over   2
1   base   3
1   over   4
1   over   5
1   under  6
```

What would be the most efficient way of counting the final occurrences of `over` ?

essentially, for the data-set above I would say `ID == 1` was last at the `Status` `over`  starting at week `4` for a total of two weeks, `4` and `5`.

My method at the moment is to sort my `df` by `ID` and `Week`, then `groupby.tail()` to get the last occurrences of the over and under and sum the differences of the weeks.

I feel a bit silly as I'm sure this is a simple problem..!

target dataset

```
ID Duration of Last-Over, Start-Week, End-Week  
1, 2,                     4,           5
```

original DataFrame :

```
ID, Budget, Spend, Week, Status
1,  50,     50,    1,    base
1   50,     55,    2,    over
1   50,     50,    3,    base
1   50,     250,   4,    over
1   50,     300,   5,    over
1   50,     42,    6,    under.
```

Comment: Do you only care about the `over` parts? Your target data set only has a column for that.

Comment: The target data is set on two variables which I've excluded from this column, which is set by a simple subtraction, it can have three outcomes, base when both values are equal to 0, over when it's greater than 0 and under when it's less than 0. For now my only requirement is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code below does that in two steps:

```
last = df[df.Status == 'over'][::-1][0:1].index
before_last = df[df.Status == 'over'][::-1][1:2].index
diff = df.iloc[last,3].values - df.iloc[before_last,3].values +1
ID = df.iloc[last,0]

new_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: ID.values[0]}, 
                       'Duration of Last-Over':  {0: diff[0]}, 
                       'Start-Week':  {0: df.iloc[before_last]['Week'].values[0]}, 
                       'End-Week':  {0: df.iloc[last]['Week'].values[0]}})
```

Producing this output:

[image]

**EDIT:** maybe a more simple answer:

Getting just the last two occurrences of 'over' and manipulate it.

```
df_aux = df[df.Status == 'over'].tail(2)
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: df_aux.iloc[1,0]}, 
                       'Duration of Last-Over':  {0: df_aux.iloc[1,3] - df_aux.iloc[0,3] +1}, 
                       'Start-Week':  {0: df_aux.iloc[0,3]}, 
                       'End-Week':  {0: df_aux.iloc[1,3]}})
```

Comment: I get the error : `IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds`  for the code on line 3 `diff` just for your edification, my DF has 450 unique IDs, will that make a difference?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference. Let me explore a bit the problem.

Comment: Could you please send me the structure of the original df? I guess the problem is with the columns.

Comment: yes, I've just edited it for you - hopefully that's clear, sorry I wasn't sure how to create the df from scratch..!

Comment: @Datanovice, edited. But I will edit again with a more simple answer in a few seconds.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think my initial question was clear,  I wanted all of the last occurrences of 'over' but and it's final occurrence in the example it was only two, but in my DF it could be 5, 15 , 25 or 40 or any number between 1-52 and I'd like to return every unique ID (around 450 occurance once for 47 weeks)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189093/discussion-between-daniel-labbe-and-datanovice).